# Building a Custom Khan Academy

Tags: web-hosting, moodle, openwrt, dnsmasq, khan-academy

I am a math teacher in a junior high classroom. I am interested in creating a customized Khan Academy-style website for my students to use next year. I have been doing a lot of research at this point and before I really sink my teeth into the project, I am hoping to get some guidance and make sure I have "most" of my ducks in a row.  Here is an explanation of my vision:

Firstly, the website needs to be hosted somewhere like GoDaddy or Siteground. Khan Academy's code is open source so I am planning to rely heavily on some of their packages. I want to basically create my own videos, host them on YouTube and deliver custom questions using KA's Perseus (https://github.com/Khan/perseus/blob/master/README.md) package. Students need to have their own logins to access the content. I have considered using Moodle for that but I am unsure if all these parts would cooperate well together.

Finally, the wifi at the school is unreliable and I don't want to depend on an internet connection. I've looked into flashing a router with OpenWRT and using a LAN network to deliver the Perseus questions while at school. For simplicity, I could DNS mask the local server at something like school(dot)myclass(dot)com where the cloud hosted site would be www(dot)myclass(dot)com.

Are there any glaring problems with my plans? Are there other major things that I should consider? Is there something else I may have overlooked that makes this any easier?

Thank you in advance,

A determined math teacher.